# Is it possible to intercept all the response http codes in Selenium Web Driver?

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to log response code using Selenium Web Driver? 
I would like to listen to all response codes that come to the browser and invoke a method when `412` status code is returned.

**Question**: Is it possible to intercept all the response http codes in Selenium Web Driver?